# Concatenate a list of tuples with a variable

Tags: python

I have a list of tuples like below.

```
tuples = [('row_id', 'Integer'), ('name', 'String')]
```

What i am trying to achieve is to get a output like below.

```
new_tuple = [abc('row_id', 'Integer'),abc('name', 'String')]
```

below is my code

```
new_list=[]
for i in tuples:
    new_list = "abc" .join(i)
```

But the result is not what i am expecting; can someone help me to rectify it.

Comment: I don't see why you're using `.join` here. Do you only want `"abc"` to be prepended to every tuple in the output of the list?

Comment: I think you want [`itertools.starmap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.starmap). (What you show is a list expression that produces a list of function *return values*, not literal strings.) For example, `new_list = list(starmap(abc, tuples))`.

Comment: You can accomplish the same thing with a list comprehension: `new_list = [abc(x, y) for x, y in tuples]`. More generally, `[abc(*args) for args in tuples]`; `starmap` simply abstracts away the unpacking of an individual tuple for passing the arguments to `abc`.

Comment: To be clear, are you trying to call the `abc` function against each of your tuples, or are you trying to prepend the *string* `"abc"` to string-ified versions of each of your tuples?  Or something else?

Comment: abc is not a function, just a variable that i am trying to prepend with each of the tuple in the list. so with new_list = [abc(x, y) for x, y in tuples] i am getting error <name 'abc' is not defined>. i tried to put it as a string new_list = ["abc"(x, y) for x, y in tuples] in that case also it's throwing <str object is not callable>.